# How to use multiple string literals at once

Tags: python, string, byte, rawstring

I have a string of bytes that I am trying to use in an re:

```
user_name = 'Simon'
string = 'Hello {user_name}, nice to see you! :)'
```

However as well as using bytes an re string should be a raw string (`r`).

So how can I specify bytes, f-strings and raw strings at once?

I tried:

```
user_name = rb'Simon'
string = brf'Hello {user_name}, nice to see you! :)'
```

But:

```
In [1]: user_name = rb'Simon'
   ...: string = brf'Hello {user_name}, nice to see you! :)'
  File "<ipython-input-8-93fb315cc66f>", line 2
    string = brf'Hello {user_name}, nice to see you! :)'
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [2]:
```

I also tried `format()` but that failed:

```
In [2]: string = br'Hello {}, nice to see you! :)'.format(user_name)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-36faa39ba31d> in <module>()
----> 1 string = br'Hello {}, nice to see you! :)'.format(user_name)

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'

In [3]:
```

How can specify multiple string literals?

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say you are trying to have one variable hold 3 different types of data at the same time?

Comment: @ScottHunter  No.  I am trying to hold *one* raw byte array (with a value substituted, hence the f-string).  I would like to do away with the `r` completely but `re` module seems to highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation is limited to *strings* and can't be used on *bytes*. This is addressed [in the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#no-binary-f-strings):

> For the same reason that we don't support `bytes.format()`, you may not
>   combine 'f' with 'b' string literals. The primary problem is that an
>   object's `__format__()` method may return Unicode data that is not
>   compatible with a bytes string.

---

The workaround is to manually encode the string to bytes:

```
>>> rf'Hello {user_name}, nice to see you! :)'.encode()
b'Hello Simon, nice to see you! :)'
```